# Python Pie Chart from User Input

Tags: python

I am trying to make a pie chart using user input. I am getting the error code "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'". I have tried fixing it, but not sure how. Below is the code I currently have and I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
    m = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
    y = []

    for i in range(12):
        x = input(f"Enter the sales for {(m[i])}: ")
        y.append(x)

    colors = ["#4D4038","#BAA892","#5B6870","#6E99B4","#A3D6D7","#085C11","#849E2A","#C3BE0B","#E9E45B","#6B4536","#B46012","#FF9B1A"]
    labels = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title("Monthly Sales Values")
    ax.pie(y, colors, labels)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I have tried putting float in front of the input and still no luck.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [**full text** of the traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the documentation of `plt.pie`is the order of the arguments different.
If you do it like this it works:

```
ax.pie(y,labels=labels, colors=colors)
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is it, `.pie(x, explode=None, labels=None, colors=None,...` is how `plt.pie` is formatted, so colors are currently being passed to explode.

Comment: I just tried to run it without adding them as key arguments, just in the right order, didnt work either.

Comment: @Rabinzel Technically `ax.pie(y, None, labels, colors)` works.

Comment: @Evanlee11 glad I could help. Would happy to see if you also accept my answer and vote, thanks :) as some extra stuff, I just recently had to do one aswell, if you want the numbers in the pie, just add `autopct="%0.0f%%"` or whatever format you need. also `startangle` as parameter to make a bit nicer.

Comment: @BeRT2me yep, tested it and worked. Is that in general the case, that I have to provide every single input in the order as defined when calling a function only with arguments? Never really noticed that...

Comment: It depends on whether or not the function asks for *Positional* or *Keyword* arguments. `ax.pie()` has one 'Positional'/'Mandatory' argument (`x`) and 12+ 'Keyword'/'Optional' arguments. You can treat keyword arguments as positional arguments... but that means that if you want to use the 12th keyword argument positionally, you have to supply the function with all 11 arguments that come before it. For a function like this, it's much easier to supply it with the correct keywords as needed.